# Can I tell my beans to not inject to a certain library / class?

Tags: dependency-injection, javabeans, micronaut

I'm using an external library which has

```
@Inject 
private Optional<DataSource> dataSource;
```

which I would very much like to leave empty.

In my service I have 2 DataSources (read and write, and read only). When I run my program I get the error:

```
Message: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [javax.sql.DataSource, javax.sql.DataSource]
```

because it doesn't know which DataSource to use. How can I tell it to use neither?

Here are my datasource Beans

```
@Factory
public class DataSourceFactory {

    @Singleton
    @Named("read-only")
    public DataSource dataSource(ReadOnlyDataSourceConfig config) {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(config.getUrl());
        hikariConfig.setUsername(config.getUsername());
        hikariConfig.setPassword(config.getPassword());
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(config.getDriverClassName());
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Named("read-and-write")
    public DataSource dataSource(ReadAndWriteDataSourceConfig config) {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(config.getUrl());
        hikariConfig.setUsername(config.getUsername());
        hikariConfig.setPassword(config.getPassword());
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(config.getDriverClassName());
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

}
```

Is it possible to configure my DataSource Beans to prevent injection into the external library, or a specific class or package?

I tried using @Named but that doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: @RoarS. Typo, I've edited.

Comment: Can you show us the class where the `@Inject` lives?

Comment: One of the possibilities would be to override bean instantiaton within custom `@Factory` class where you annotate the bean as `@Primary` and construct it as you wish.